# How to draw a lot of rectangles on canvas with good performance?

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, canvas, 2d

I've got to render a cinema hall map with sectors, rows and seats.
Currently I have around 1000 of seats (filled rectangles) to draw and I'm doing this for every seat by calling:

```
canvas.drawRect(seatRect, seatPaint)
```

My view must also support scaling, scrolling and fling.
The performance is awful. I tried to improve it by explicitly enabling hardware acceleration but nothing changed, it seems it was enabled by default on my Nexus 4 (Api 22)

Could you please suggest any methods to render huge number of rectangles at high speed ? So movement, scaling animation is smooth.

**Custom View class code:**

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor); // scaling support
    canvas.translate(mTranslateX, mTranslateY); // scrolling support

    if (mEventMap != null) {
        mEventMap.paint(canvas);
    }

    canvas.restore();
}
```

**EventMap code:**

```
public void paint(Canvas canvas) {
    for (EventPlace place : places) {
        if (place.isSelected())
            placePaint.setColor(0xFF00FF00);
        else if (place.isAvailable())
            placePaint.setColor(place.getColor());
        else
            placePaint.setColor(0xFF000000);

        canvas.drawRect(place.getBounds(), placePaint);
    }
}
```

None of the methods called in onDraw create any instances.
There are just a LOT of rectangles...

Comment: Can you please post the code of your onDraw method?

Comment: Without seeing your code I can only suggest that you may have put too much new objects allocation in the onDraw, and thus I can suggest creating the Path instance somewhere before you dispatch draw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem that you have right now is basically the fact that you perform a large amount of drawing cycles (equal to the number of Rects you have) it's better to store all those rects in [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) object, in order to reduce number of drawing cycles. Since you have three states of seats I suggest creation of three Paths. I would suggest doing something like this:

```
private void init() {
    mSelectedPath = new Path();
    mAvailablePath = new Path();
    mUnavalablePath = new Path();

    mAvailablePaint = new Paint();
    mSelectedPaint = new Paint();
    mUnavalablePaint = new Paint();

    mUnavalablePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mSelectedPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    mAvailablePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    for (EventPlace place : mData) {
        if (place.isSelected())
            mSelectedPath.addRect(rectF, Path.Direction.CW);
        else if (place.isAvailable())
            mAvailablePath.addRect(rectF, Path.Direction.CW);
        else
            mUnavalablePath.addRect(rectF, Path.Direction.CW);
    }
}
```

Then when you want to associate date with this View you should do something like this:

```
public void setData(List<EventPlace> data) {
    mData = data;
    init();
    invalidate();
}
```

Actually you can do it however you like, just keep in mind that you have to call init method and then invalidate. And in the onDraw:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor); // scaling support
    canvas.translate(mTranslateX, mTranslateY); // scrolling support

    canvas.drawPath(mAvailablePath, mAvailablePaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mUnavalablePath, mUnavalablePaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mSelectedPath, mSelectedPaint);

    canvas.restore();
}
```

Perhaps you would also want to add some logics to exclude those Rects that are not visible at the moment from paths in order to tweak performance.

I tried animating my approach on test set of Rects and it was running smoothly with 200 rects, I didn't try performing a serious benchmark though

Comment: I tried your approach and must say the performance got better but not too much. First of all my hall map has ~4000 of places, adding all of those into a single Path object caused application hanging followed by a crash. So I created multiple Path(es) holding no more than 200 of rectangles.

Comment: ... but still it does not render smoothly. 
I have to optimize rendering by not drawing out of view range rectangles but since they are all added into a Path which does not support removal I need to find a better approach.
Going further I also have the corresponding huge hall background image (3000x2142) which I need to render, this also slows down rendering performance.
Not sure if there is a better approach but I'm drawing the background and then rectangles in natural size and coords and then apply scaling and translation to the canvas

Comment: As for background I would suggest dividing it into chunks and loading only those chunks that are likely to be displayed, as for path approach I think in this case it has to be modified in this case - you should initialize paths with only those rectangles that are visible right now (basically each time you pan or scroll view it will require new paths creation), I guess drawing of all the rectangles and background might be computationally intensive,  I would also suggest modify canvas only for background and for rectangles it's better to modify paths

Comment: I went for OpenGL solution since performance was not good and I event didn't add text titles over each of the seats. Will post a link to the solution once it's ready

Comment: @ievgen, yes, with OpenGL it is much easier to solve this problem

Comment: Implemented a solution, here it is, as promised: https://github.com/ykrapiva/android-eventmap-library